# How do I go back to the other view mode?

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, edges, object-mode

I want go back to the original look of the mesh. Just white and gray but I don't how to get out of it.

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I did a quick search and didn't find anything like this, which I kind of can't believe.  Because of course someone could press shift+z in the wrong context and go to wireframe with no indication as to why and be totally bewildered.

Answer (score 1):

*Viewport Shading Modes* are in the top-right corner of the viewport.

[image]

Or, hovering your mouse in the viewport you can press <kbd>Z</kbd> to open a wheel.

[image]

[Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/shading.html)

Comment: @AllenSimpson...I just realized that your profile picture is that one groundhog that kept saying "Allan! Allan! Allan!" That's hilarious! 

Comment: @BlenderMaster15 hidden secrets from the original internet